# Websraping multiple websites with links saved in a dataframe, Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, web-scraping, hyperlink

I have a dataframe called wppmorocco with a number of websites, it looks like this:

```
    URL
11  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P124639
4   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P130891
13  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P133312
14  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P133312
3   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P146970
12  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P147760
15  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P150520
7   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P151072
8   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P151072
10  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P151072
5   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P155522
16  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P155522
19  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P160661
6   http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P162637
18  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P165228
17  http://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P167788
```

I would like to open each website and extract the "abstract" text. However, soup doesn't detect the source code, so I had to use Selenium. My problem is that it also outputs an error message stating that the element couldn't be located. My end goal is to only keep the URLs that contain some specific keywords. My code for opening the links and retrieving the text is as follows:

```
description = []
#Filtering dataframe for only relevant opportunities
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
for link in wbppmorocco.iterrows():
    url = link[1]['URL']
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(20)
    desc=driver.find_element_by_class_name('more _loop_lead_paragraph_sm')
    print(desc.text)
    description.append(desc)
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried finding the elements by their xpaths?

Comment: @Samuel the xpath is different from link to link

Answer (score 1):

The worldbank website that you use is doing HTTP (API) call in order to get the data for you.

*You can do that as well.*

Here is a functional example:

```
import requests

ids = [12,45,67] # dummy ids
for _id in ids :
    r = requests.post(f'https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&fl=*&id={_id}}&apilang=en')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(r.json())
    else:
        print(r.status_code)
```

So all you have to do is to loop over the project ids you have and read the data.

Comment: Hey thanks! but how do you retrieve and loop through individual IDs knowing that they are frequently updated ? Could you please show me an example ? I am not sure how to implement this..

Comment: You already have the IDs in the df - isn't it?

Comment: yes but how do you implement this in code ? do you have an example ?

Comment: @zaza001 answer was updated with the code you requested.

Comment: Hey thanks! When I add some IDs, I get the following output, which is not the text: ><SortOrder>TG02</SortOrder><ValueComments/></ParentTransaction><ParentTransaction><ProjectId>P167788</ProjectId><IndicatorID>IN01013237</IndicatorID><ValueType>TG</ValueType><ValueDate/><ValueCalendar>0</ValueCalendar><ValueFiscal/><VALUE/><SortOrder>TG03</SortOrder><ValueComments/></ParentTransaction><ParentTransaction><ProjectId>P167788</ProjectId><IndicatorID>IN01013237< etc. Any ideas how to adjudicate this ?

Comment: Do you get other response type as well?

Comment: @balderman, using *f-string* to pass parameters is not a good practice, better to pass them in `params` argument: `r = requests.post('https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects', params={'format': 'json', 'fl': '*', 'id': _id, 'apilang': 'en'})`. Also it's kinda weird that data in post request passed using get parameters, probably it's a misunderstanding and all this params have to be sent on body *(in that case same dict you can pass into `data` argument)*.

Comment: That still doesn't output the text though